# How To Add PasteValues To PasteDestination VBA Code?

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, paste

I want to add a line of code to copy only the values of column C with no formatting.

Part of my code currently looks like this:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = FISH Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    erow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 1)
```

I found a simple PasteValues method online which states the following:

```
Range("A1:A3").Copy
Range("B1:B3").pastespecial xlPasteValues
```

However what I actually want is to add the PasteValues into my existing code.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the values then skip the clipboard and assign the values directly:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = FISH Then
    erow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
End If
```

---

If you are determined to use the clipboard then:

```
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = FISH Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Copy
    erow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

But this will be slower, especially in a loop.